# How to configure Apache httpd to set multi-site for multi-user?

Tags: django, centos, apache

I have a system CentOS with Django and MySQL.

```
/home/user1/
    -/vhost/*.conf
    -/webapps/
        abc.com
        xyz.com

/home/user2/
    -/vhost/*.conf
    -/webapps/
        123.com
        789.com
```

Thanks for help!

UPDATE 1:
In httpd.conf:

```
User user1
Group apache
```

And httpd cannot access /home/user2/webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read up on [Apache Vhost Configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/).

Tell us what you tried, what is working, what is not working, or what you don't understand.

### Most common configuration

If your system has 1 IP address for all sites, you're going to want something like this:

```
#This is your 'default' host, 
#people accessing the site via IP-address will see this site.
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName abc.com
        ServerAlias xyz.com
        DocumentRoot /home/user1/webapps/
</VirtualHost>

#This is the 123 and 789 vhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 123.com
        ServerAlias 789.com
        DocumentRoot /home/user2/webapps/
</VirtualHost>
```

You can add all directives as explained by the [`<VirtualHost> Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost)

### EDIT: Updated question

1. There is a [module called
   perchild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/perchild.html) for apache that allows
   to run different threads under
   different users, configurable by
   vhost. The module is not considered
   functional, and not under current
   development. Unless you know what
   you're doing or are willing to take
   the risk, you probably shouldn't use
   it.
2. Another solution might be mpm-itk,
   which appears to be more reliable.
   Read [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/146700/thoughts-on-mpm-itk)
   for more information, or visit their
   [homepage](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/).
3. If you don't want to use either of both modules, you could always create a new user and group, run both vhosts under that user, and make both homedirs readable to the user by setting their group to the new group.

Comment: I am very glad with your answers. It's really clear. Thx :) Here is the solution I used: http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2010/04/mpm-itk-on-centos/

Comment: If you really need this feature, mpm-itk indeed looks like the best option :)